# Unable to install Tensorflow on R Studio on Windows 11

Tags: windows, tensorflow, rstudio

I installed-

1. Rstudio
2. R 4.1.2
   3)Anaconda
   4)Python 3.9

The command I tried to execute-
install.packages("tensorflow")
install_tensorflow

The error I get after executing these-

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/tensorflow/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.7.* (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.7.*
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Error: Error installing package(s): ""tensorflow==2.7.*""

Comment: It is asking to upgrade pip, `pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools`. Before installing Tensorflow R package.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I tried to upgrade pip but, I got a message saying the requirement is already satisfied.

Comment: HI Nnna17, Kindly install Python and TensorFlow on your system prior to using the tensorflow R package and follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/install/) to install Tensorflow in Rstuido. Thank you!